# AWS beanstalk htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I have created an instance using AWS Elastic beanstalk; However, on deploying my code zip (containing .htaccess), I am unable to see the uploaded .htaccess file using SSH/WINSCP. 
I need to define htaccess so that I can host a separate blog in a subdirectory. Right now, when I enter www.example.com/xyz. It's not reading XYZ as a directory.  and showing 404 error.

My Question: If there is some solution I can make the main website treat directory as a directory instead of its normal page.

Note: I have changed "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" file line from 
    `<Files ".ht*"> Require all denied</Files>`
to
     `<Files ".ht*"> Require all granted</Files>`
No success.

Comment: .htaccess is a hidden file did you use this command ls -la to see if htaccess is there using ssh

Comment: Hi, I have checked via SSH ls -a, no success. 
Is there any way I can access directory directly?